# Can I open the Numbers spreadsheet application from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have programmatically created a CSV file in Swift that I'm currently allowing the user to open using a `UIActivityViewController`.

However, as it's a CSV, it'd be nice to have it automatically open in Numbers rather than have users guess what app to open it in.

I can't find a scheme name for the Numbers app (which I'm wondering suggests they don't allow the behaviour I'm looking for).

Comment: Why assume the user wants to open the CSV file in Numbers? That's what's nice about `UIActivityViewController`. It allows the *user* to choose what to do with the file. They may have some other app they want to use. Or they might want to email it or print it, etc.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy don't force the choice upon the user let them decide what to do with it.  If you don't do that how will you handle the situation if they don't have Numbers installed.

Comment: I agree too, but Numbers is one of the only in-built apps on the iPhone that actually makes sense to open a CSV... most people won't know what a CSV is and might try opening it in Notes, for example so they'll just see a load of strings listed, rather than a table and think that it's a bug.

Is there a way of prioritising the first app in the UIActivityViewController to make Numbers as the first suggested app?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller